How to fix "Maximum call stack size exceeded" with Datatables in Astro
I tried to use Datatables in Astro, the error occur when I export csv.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.4/luxon.js" is:inline/>
<script is:inline src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-2.0.7/datatables.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.7/sorting/ip-address.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.7/sorting/file-size.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/3.0.2/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/3.0.2/js/buttons.dataTables.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/3.0.0/js/buttons.colVis.js"></script>
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/3.0.0/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>

 $(`#myTable`).DataTable({
            lengthMenu: [[10, 100, 500, 1000, -1], [10, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]],
            layout: {
                bottomStart: 'info',
                bottomEnd: ['pageLength', {paging: {type: 'simple_numbers'}}],
                top1Start: {
                    buttons: ['colvis', 'csvHtml5', 'excelHtml5']
                },
                topStart: ['info'],
                topEnd: ['pageLength', {paging: {type: 'simple_numbers'}}],
                top1End: ['search']
            },
            data: generateRandomData(10000),
            initComplete: () => {
                $('.dt-length label').remove();
                $('.dt-length').parent().addClass('!flex justify-end items-center gap-x-2');
            }
        });

Get the error


It happened in Astro, but I try the same code on codepen, it's not occur. I have no idea problem with astro

What's the HTML for the #myTable? If you have the exact same HTML and client-side JS, you should be able to reproduce it in a codepen independently of astro. Either way, maximum-call-stack-size exceeded means most probably that there is an infinite recursion going on, or the data is just too big for how the code is written.

html in #mytable only
`


Order
Description
Deadline
Status
Amount


`
it the same my code in astro

In Astro you have generateRandomData(10000) as well? can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
